# Android: navigate through Activity hierarchy

Tags: java, android, navigation

My application has a logical Activity hierarchy, as follows:

[image: Activity Hierarchy]

I'm trying to navigate across Activities while checking if they're running. For instance:

Main Menu > Activity A1 > Activity A2.

Now if I go back to Main Menu, is there a way to check if Activity A2 is already running, and if so, jump directly to that Activity?

I think setting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to Activity A1 might do the trick, and read about the `android:allowTaskReparenting` attribute. But i'm unsure exactly what to use to achieve what I want.

Comment: Are you interested in taking decisions based on navigation history or particularly in the back stack reordering?

Comment: @MaximG Navigation history isn't really a concern, unless one or more of the Activities in the "A category" have been created and not destroyed - in which case I need to navigate to the deepest in the hierarchy

Comment: Did you check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?

Comment: @MaximG I have, it was all still a bit unclear though. Will re-read it in depth

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use one host Activity (as a navigation controller ) and many Fragments. Current Fragment will callback to the Activity, so it will make decision how to navigate on your graph.

If you really want to stick to the graph with many Activities, default behaviour - all activities in the same process will be alive. Android OS can only clean/kill process, not Activities (documentation a bit vague about it). You can use Intent.[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) for middle activities, so only root one will be on the stack.

There is a way to investigate back stack with [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29), but it's deprecated.

Comment: Ideally I would've liked to launch whatever activity is on top of the particular task (created with `android:launchMode="singleTask`). To my understanding there is no way to do this? Maybe I'll rework everything and make fragments instead